# Calling app_code folder from web application project

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am developing a module for DotNetNuke and have used a DotNetNuke Compiled Module template to create the module in the DesktopModule folder.

I then get a Web Application Project under the DNN website in my Visual Studio 2008.

Now I want to use DAL and BLL which are created in DNN app_code folder.

But when I add them in code behind it can't find them.

How do I tell my Web Application Project to access the app_code folder in the website "projcet"?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the web application the Components folder seems to do what app_code folder does.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. App_Code is compiled on-the-fly, but even if you compile it prior to deployment somehow, you will have a circular reference (App_Code -> Web Application -> App_Code).

Comment: Yeah, but the Web Application Project does not have the App_code folder. But it make sens what you are writing.